# Deleted Bootcamp partition through disk utility and messed up everything

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I deleted my bootcamp partition to redo the whole process to make a higher capacity windows system. Then I tried bootcamp again and it says "Your disk could not be partitioned" and "An error occurred while partitioning the disk. Please run Disk Utility to check and fix the error." 
I ran disk utility in the recovery and deleted any partitions but 1 of them I couldn't fix. 
How do I fix this? I want to make a bigger windows bootcamp os

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After you delete all of your partitions except your main OSX one you need to reclaim all the extra space for your main partition and then run bootcamp again to split your drive up again to install windows.